# Using multiple RPlidar on a single system

Tags: serial, laser, ros-kinetic, multiple, 2dlidar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

i would like to use two (or more) rplidars at the same time. When i start the second RPLIDARnode, the first one closes.
I tried to find a connection to rosserial, but it seems rplidarnode doesnt use it at all.
Is there a way to run both rplidar with two rplidarnodes? What changes do i need to do?
Right now im trying to use an Arduino Microcontroller to read out the rplidar and publish its informations by using rosserial_python. At the moment this wont work out pretty well cause it needs a lot of Parameters and really big Arrays (Timing Problems)...

My goal is to use multiple rplidar for sensor Fusion :)

Regards
Dave

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320377/using-multiple-rplidar-on-a-single-system/) by [Vladith](https://answers.ros.org/users/32955/vladith/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2019-04-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to launch them in namespaces or use a different name attribute for each node and remap the topics to be different. With the namspaces you could use something like the following.

`rplidar_arg.launch`

```
<launch>
  <arg name="serial_port" default="/dev/ttyUSB0"/>
  <node name="rplidarNode"          pkg="rplidar_ros"  type="rplidarNode" output="screen">
  <param name="serial_port"         type="string" value="$(arg serial_port)"/>
  <param name="serial_baudrate"     type="int"    value="115200"/><!--A1/A2 -->
  <!--param name="serial_baudrate"     type="int"    value="256000"--><!--A3 -->
  <param name="frame_id"            type="string" value="laser"/>
  <param name="inverted"            type="bool"   value="false"/>
  <param name="angle_compensate"    type="bool"   value="true"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

`two_lidars.launch`

```
<launch>
    <include ns="lidar0" file="$(find your_ros_package)/launch/rplidar_arg.launch">
        <arg name="serial_port" value="/dev/ttyUSB0"/>
    </include>
    <include ns="lidar1" file="$(find your_ros_package)/launch/rplidar_arg.launch">
        <arg name="serial_port" value="/dev/ttyUSB1"/>
    </include>
</launch>
```

the resulting topics would look something like, so in whatever nodes you use the scan topics in need to be listening to the correct topics:

```
/lidar0/scan
/lidar1/scan
```

---

Originally posted by [Reamees](https://answers.ros.org/users/36207/reamees/) with karma: 591 on 2019-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2